# Why pytesseract can't handle OSD mode?

Tags: python, ocr, tesseract, python-tesseract

I cant run **OSD** mode in **pytesseract** on docker image on Ubuntu. On windows, this command works like charm:

```
pytesseract.image_to_osd(image)
```

But inside docker image, it causes the following error. What I want to achieve is reading the rotation info using OSD.

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pytesseract/pytesseract.py", line 263, in run_tesseract
raise TesseractError(proc.returncode, get_errors(error_string))pytesseract.pytesseract.TesseractError: (1, 'Tesseract Open Source OCR Engine v5.0.0-alpha-20210401 with Leptonica UZN file /tmp/tess__cujlspf loaded. Estimating resolution as 169 UZN file /tmp/tess__cujlspf loaded. Warning. Invalid resolution 0 dpi. Using 70 instead. Too few characters. Skipping this page Error during processing.')
```

Tesseract is installed correctly because all other methods like image_to_string are working properly. The suprising thing is that when I call the OSD directly from terminal, it works

```
tesseract /images/1.jpg  output --psm 0
# cat output.osd
Page number: 0
Orientation in degrees: 0
Rotate: 0
Orientation confidence: 5.69
Script: Cyrillic
Script confidence: 0.10
```

Is there some bug in Pytesseract or any workaround? The rotation info is not included in any other Tesseract methods, only in this OSD.
Many thanks

Comment: Did you find the solution?

Comment: No, I just run that command from terminal and read the response through it. Directly from pytesseract it doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for this by adding the config arguments to the method call:

```
pytesseract.image_to_osd(file_name,config='--psm 0 -c min_characters_to_try=5')
```

This solves the error and I could get the angle data.